# Using rand function with HQL to select

Tags: hibernate, jpa, random, hql

To get list of 10 random unique objects with Hql I have this methode but i had an error

```
    String sRequete = "select p from TgQuestionnaire p where p.id.idAnnee = :paramAnnee order by rand()";


    try{


        //sRequete = sRequete + " order by p.id.cdQuestionnaire ";

        Query requete = entityManager.createQuery(sRequete);

        if (resultat_max != null && resultat_max > 0) {
            requete.setMaxResults(resultat_max);
        }

        requete.setParameter("paramAnnee", idAnnee);



        listeEnteteQuestionnaire = (List<TgQuestionnaire>) requete
                .getResultList();
        if (listeEnteteQuestionnaire.size() == 0) {
            listeEnteteQuestionnaire = new ArrayList<TgQuestionnaire>();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("erreur bdd pendant la recherche des entêtes de questionnaire :"
                + e.getMessage());
    }
    return listeEnteteQuestionnaire;
}
```

ERROR:
2015/04/03 16:14:39,264 WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
2015/04/03 16:14:39,264 ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-00904: "RAND" : identificateur non valide

Comment: I use:
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar and
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar

Comment: As any JPQL reference would say, there is no "rand" keyword. If you wanted to use a Database function in JPA 2.1 you could use FUNCTION to access it. You're not using JPA 2.1 so you cannot do this with JPQL and have to use createNativeQuery, or just reorder them yourself when returned.

Comment: thx for your response.
it's possible to reorder them after returned.But in my data base i have 500 000 of object.and i want just to returned 20 or 30 objects ,that's why i use (requete.setMaxResults(resultat_max);).so i can't returned all of them